# Custom filter component for multiple tables - Angular

Tags: angular

I have multiple Tables which gets populated from the data coming from different API's in my website. For all the tables I would like to creat a filter component which consists of respective table column names and respective filter criteria (switch, checkbox, drop down, textbox, date range,input range) to enter and click on Apply.

Once specific parameters are entered, I need to filter the Table based on the selected parameters.

I have 5 tables with different Columns data (Products, Customers , Risk, Errors, Signals). How to make a generic filter component for all the tables? where to write the code logic?

How to pass different columns data and how to form controls? example: Product table filter needs Product Name Text box and product Active switch to show inside filter component. Customers Table filter needs Customer Region Dropdown and Customer Age number textbox to show inside filter component. So, different tables need different type of filters. In this case how to architect a re-usable component?

Comment: This is too broad. My advise: make a specific filter component for one table. Then make another specific filter component for the second one. Thene even maybe one for the third table. Then see what is common between those 2/3 components, and what is specific to a given table. See if it's useful to refactor it into something generic. See what needs to be passed as input to the generic component so that it works for every specific case. Based on your description, you should probably not try to make a generic component.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your reply. As per your comment I should not use re-usable component. Yes, I am also thinking the same. If I chose specific component architecture, then where to write the filter component code? I dont want to disturb the table code with this.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You need to crite the code in a TypeScript file, like for any other component.

Comment: What I mean is , I have x - component having table and y-component also having table component. So, I need to create filtercomponent.ts file for each component's folder.. :)

Comment: Yes. So... do it, like you do for any other component. What's the issue?

Comment: No issue, Thanks JB.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a component and call it where you want:)

### Ok ... nice idea

you can make the of filter type as input 
and you will make the input type dependent with field type such as (if string: textbox, if boolean: switch ... etc ) and you can use `typeof` to determine the type.
and you can know the properties of class using code like this 
`export class showClassComponent {
    var classes = [ { name: 'workBookEntity', value: new WorkBookEntity() }]

```
whenSubmitedInHtmlForm(className: string): void {
    let c = classes.filter(class => class.name == className)[0];
    if(c) {
        let ret = [];

        for (var key in c) {
            if (c.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                ret.push({ name: key, value: c[key] });
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
}

// more code there
```

}`

you will use some conditions on Typescript and HTML, that is up to your logic.
I hope to be helped you

Comment: Hi Rabea, Thanks for your reply. I implemented this and the code has been grown and unable to maintain. Becausem if any new control I want to implement (example: 3rd party text boxes or calenders or any other) I need to write the full logic again and they have their own events so I need to extend the current one and add the new events .. omg.. If I want to give my code to another person, I am  not feeling happy.. why.. where is the wrong in my architecture :(

Comment: I think you need just to improve your design patterns, so I think you should implement just for each data type such as (string & char: textbox, boolean: switch, number & float: textbox, array: select list ....etc)